# how to remove the appended elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

By right-clicking on each picture, the picture will be removed, and a new item will be created by clicking on the + button.

But the problem is that the new items that are created (appended) could not be removed. Why is this the case?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let nextItem = 4;
  $(".items div").click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    $(".items").append(`<div id="${nextItem}"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/${nextItem - 1}/200/100" alt=""></div>`);
    nextItem++;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
    <div id="1"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/0/200/100" alt=""></div>
    <div id="2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/100" alt=""></div>
    <div id="3"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/100" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because those aren't targeted by the event handler. It doesn't automatically update the elements which are matching the query selector, it's the same as if you'd used `addEventHandler` - it runs once. (see below where they don't log a message to the console but the hardcoded ones do).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let nextItem = 4;
  $(".items div").click(function() {
    console.log("Event processed");
  });
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    $(".items").append(`<div id="${nextItem}"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/${nextItem - 1}/200/100" alt=""></div>`);
    nextItem++;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
    <div id="1"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/0/200/100" alt=""></div>
    <div id="2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/100" alt=""></div>
    <div id="3"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/100" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn">+</button>
</div>
```

Instead what I would do is define that removal as a function and re-add it to the new element using the `id`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let nextItem = 4;
  function removeItem() {
    $(this).remove();
  }
  $(".items div").click(removeItem);
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    $(".items").append(`<div id="${nextItem}"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/${nextItem - 1}/200/100" alt=""></div>`);
    $(`#${nextItem}`).click(removeItem);
    nextItem++;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
    <div id="1"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/0/200/100" alt=""></div>
    <div id="2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/100" alt=""></div>
    <div id="3"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/100" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use live events https://api.jquery.com/live/
since you're creating a new Dom element and not attaching the click event again

```
$(".items div").live('click',function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let nextItem = 4;
  $(".items div").click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    $(".items").append(`<div id="${nextItem}"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/${nextItem - 1}/200/100" alt=""></div>`);
    nextItem++;
  })
  $(`div#${nextItem}`).on('click',function(){
     $(this).remove();
  })
});
```